# Error in jupyter notebook after importing visualisation libraries

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization, data-analysis

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
%matplotlib inline  
import seaborn as sns
```

I keep recieving:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: it seems it needs some C/C++ library `arpack` and you may have to install it separatelly. It is not python module and you can't use `pip` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I fixed the problem by forcing the removing of Numpy,seaborn and scipy
then used to install :

```
pip install seaborn numpy scipy
```

I rechecked jupyter notebook and it works just fine.